# Magento 2 Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on string

Tags: fatal-error, magento2

Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on string in/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2_new/Sourcecode/app/design/frontend/Emthemes/em0150jewelry/jewelry/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml on line 539.This error occured by using a function 
`$optionText=$_product->getId()->getAttributeText('Farben');`
How can I resolve this in magento 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are getting the id, I am not so sure but I think the following code will work :

```
$optionText=$_product->getAttributeText('Farben');
```

If not comment